# Trace of a Product of Finitely Many Matrices with Cosine Entry

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, polynomials

Can someone help me prove the following identity?
$$
\mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}  
2\cos\frac{2j\pi}{n} & -m \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right)=
\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if } n=1\pmod{2}\\
2m^{\frac{n}{2}} & \text{if } n=0\pmod{4}\\
-2m^{\frac{n}{2}}-4 & \text{if } n=2\pmod{4}\\
\end{cases},
$$

For the 1st equality, since the product of $2\cos\frac{2j\pi}{n}$'s is 2 when $n$ is odd, we only need to prove that the trace is a constant polynomial in $m$. However, because of the cosine term, the approach of polynomial analysis given in [my previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213246/product-of-a-finite-number-of-matrices-related-to-roots-of-unity) does not seem to work here.

Situations are the same for the 2nd and 3rd equalities.

Comment: The product is such that the first matrix is the one for $j=0$, etc.?

Comment: The first matrix (when $j=0$) is {{2,-m},{1,0}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this can be evaluated by expanding cos as a sum of exponentials.

Let $\zeta=\exp(2i\pi/n)$. Consider the set $X$ of $n$-tuples $x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\in\{+,-,1,-m\}$
where for each $j$ we require $x_j=1$ if and only if $x_{j-1}=-m$. Subscripts are modulo $n$.

Define $w_j(+)=\zeta^j$ and $w_j(-)=\zeta^{-j}$ and $w_j(1)=1$ and $w_j(-m)=-m$.
Expanding $2\cos\frac{2j\pi}{n}=w_j(+)+w_j(-)$ gives the desired trace as $\sum_{x\in X}w(x)$ where $w(x)=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j(x_j)$.

Cyclicly permuting by moving the end element to the start has the effect of multiplying $w(x)$ by $\zeta^{N_+(x)-N_-(x)}$ where $N_+$ and $N_-$ are the number of $+$'s and $-$'s.
The total weight from sequences with $N_+(x)-N_-(x)\not\in\{-n,0,n\}$ is therefore zero.

Now we need another group action.
Given $x\in X$ that is not all $+$'s, for each maximal run of $+$'s, move the $-$ or $-m,1$ after the run to the beginning. Each replacement multiplies $w(x)$ by $\zeta^{2k}$ where $k$ is the length of the run, so this procedure gives a sequence $x'$ with $w(x')=w(x)\zeta^{2N_+(x)}$.
This shows that the total contribution from all sequences with $(N_+(x),N_-(x))=(a,b)$ is zero whenever $a\not\in\{0,n/2,n\}$.
A similar argument applies when $b\not\in\{0,n/2,n\}$.

The only non-constant terms not accounted for are those containing no $+$'s or $-$'s, i.e. $1,-m,1,-m,\dots,1,-m$ and $-m,1,-m,\dots,1,-m,1$ for even $n$,
which contribute the $2(-m)^{n/2}$.

Comment: Thanks! I have through your answer and think it makes sense. I have one question though: what does "restricting to $N_+(x)\in \{0,n/2,n\}$" in the final sentence of the penultimate paragraph mean?

Comment: @DavidSun: I've edited the answer to clarify - what I really wanted to say is that the argument applies for each fixed choice of $(N_+(x),N_-(x))$. I also found a simpler way to move the +'s; I don't think the action described before was quite what is needed.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I still don't quite understand the 4th paragraph, why the effect of moving is multiplication by $\zeta^{N_+(x)-N_-(x)}$ and why the contribution of those sequences is zero? Also, how do you recover -4 from $w(x)$ when $n=2$ (mod 4)?

Comment: @DavidSun: for the cyclic permutation, consider the product over $w_{j+1}(x_j)=w_j(x_j)\zeta^{p_j}$ where $p_j$ is $1,-1,0,0$ for $+,-,1,-m$ respectively. The existence of any permutation $g$ of a set $Y$ with $w(gx)=Cw(x)$ for fixed $C\neq 1$ proves that $\sum_{x\in Y}w(x)=C\sum_{x\in Y}w(x)$ so $\sum_{x\in Y}w(x)=0$. For the constant term I'd just evaluate it by hand in terms of cos, using $\cos\frac{2\pi (j+n/2)}{n}=-\cos\frac{2\pi j}{n}$ to write the constant term as $(-1)^{n/2}\left[\prod_{j=0}^{n/2-1} 2\cos\frac{\pi j}{n/2}\right]^2=-4$ for $n=2$ (mod 4).

Comment: I see how the permutation works now. I've got the -4 term by hand, but confused it with those non-constant terms. Thank you very much!